# Can't connect to any Wi-Fi on Asus X550C in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, asus

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 the first and the only OS on my new laptop ASUS X550C and I cannot connect to any Wi-Fi, even toggling <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> (keyboard default) doesn't swith/show Wi-Fi indicator on.

here are some outputs from my system:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2c97]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k

04:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:200f]
Kernel driver in use: r8169

iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

**edit**

```
sudo rfkill list all
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes

lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bbswitch               13615  0 
bnep                   18895  2 
rfcomm                 53664  0 
binfmt_misc            13140  1 
uvcvideo               71309  0 
intel_rapl             18301  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13048  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13170  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         39258  1 uvcvideo
arc4                   12536  2 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    13845  0 
intel_powerclamp       14239  0 
nvidia               9648068  35 
coretemp               13195  0 
ath9k                 144602  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45342  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    55125  1 
ath9k_common           13359  1 ath9k
kvm_intel             132549  0 
videodev              108503  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
i915                  705659  2 
ath9k_hw              438205  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
snd_hda_intel          42730  3 
kvm                   388083  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec         164067  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
asus_nb_wmi            16862  0 
asus_wmi               23495  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13708  1 asus_wmi
mxm_wmi                12893  0 
ath                    23922  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
drm_kms_helper         47182  1 i915
mac80211              546051  1 ath9k
rtsx_pci_ms            17807  0 
ath3k                  13110  0 
btusb                  27580  0 
cfg80211              409394  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211
crc32_pclmul           12967  0 
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                85501  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 i915
memstick               16174  1 rtsx_pci_ms
snd_page_alloc         14230  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
joydev                 17101  0 
snd_rawmidi            25135  1 snd_seq_midi
mei_me                 14099  0 
snd_seq                55383  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
bluetooth             342206  12 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
serio_raw              13230  0 
drm                   244037  5 i915,drm_kms_helper,nvidia
mei                    66737  1 mei_me
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              28584  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
mac_hid                13037  0 
lpc_ich                16864  0 
snd                    60871  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12600  1 snd
wmi                    18673  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi
video                  18903  2 i915,asus_wmi
parport_pc             31981  0 
ppdev                  17391  0 
lp                     13299  0 
parport                40836  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12492  0 
usbhid                 46997  0 
hid                    87604  2 hid_generic,usbhid
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         22693  0 
ahci                   25579  3 
r8169                  61562  0 
psmouse                91329  0 
libahci                27082  1 ahci
mii                    13654  1 r8169
rtsx_pci               43796  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
```

Comment: can you enter the command `sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 15`

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: rfkill list all Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesGreen the command that you suggested doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: @chili555 just a sec I will add the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Add a single line:

```
options asus-nb-wmi wapf=0
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot and tell us if the wireless is now working. If not, edit the file again and change the factor from 0 to 1 and reboot again. You can also try 4.

Comment: now it says: 3: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
7: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
8: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
9: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
and even button on top panel saying **enable Wi-Fi** is grey/deactivated

Comment: also when I run `sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning | egrep 'Cell |Encryption|Quality|Last beacon|ESSID'` it says `wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down`. On my old laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 WiFi worked though.

Comment: Do the Fn+F2 buttons now respond?

Comment: no they dont either

Comment: Reboot and edit your question to add: lsmod Thanks.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: thank you very much! works with `options asus-nb-wmi wapf=1`