# Wifi Disabled WLAN Hard blocked

Tags: networking, asus

I used command `rfkill list` and got:

```
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I tried unblocking my WLAN connection with `rfkill unblock <id>` but that still didn't work.

Comment: You need to take that as exactly that: there is something the OS sees as -hardware- blocking your wireless, So... keyboard (Fn+Fx), bios or an actual switch on the side of your notebook.

Comment: Please try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/499881/cant-connect-to-any-wi-fi-on-asus-x550c-in-ubuntu-14-04/499903#499903

Answer (score 1):

`rfkill` checks your wireless device for two types of blocks: a software block (your WiFi card being disabled from the OS) and a hardware block (the card being disabled by something lower-level).

In the event of a software block, one can simply re-enable the card by re-enabling wireless communications, loading the module, or running `rfkill unblock`. Easy enough.

However, with a hardware block, the OS can do *absolutely nothing* to unblock the chip. You need to either go into your BIOS and enable your wireless card, or check your computer for a button or physical switch (usually on Dell computers) and make sure it's set to the ON position.

Comment: That's not true. There are kernel wmi drivers that can misinterpret BIOS variables. That's why there are lot's of quirks in platform drivers. That is not that straight forward as it seems.