# disconnect wireless LAN immediatly after established connection

Tags: wireless, disconnect, rfkill

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

above is list of rfkill list..
when i unblock hard block of wireless LAN..my connection is established but within 2 seconds it disconnect automatically..what should i do?

Comment: What wireless card ?

Comment: i am using asus laptop ..MT7630E

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help. post the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: Install the driver - https://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working

Comment: i have install my driver..but it shows my wifi but within 2 sec it disconnect do you have solution for that ?

Comment: Update your question with that information. You may need to file a bug report against the driver.

Comment: Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/499881/cant-connect-to-any-wi-fi-on-asus-x550c-in-ubuntu-14-04/499903#499903

Comment: thank you very much chili555 you saved me from lot of struggle...